# Designing class efficiently with common method for different sub classes

Tags: c#, oop

I have this small design issue on which I want to find optimum solution.

I have a Parent class A and having objects of other classes say Class B, C..etc. I have 6 of these child classes.

Now every child class has to call some method from parent class.
The common method calls some delegate, kind of sending events from parent class.

So the structure is:

```
class ParentA
{
   Child B, C, D, E, F, G;

   CommonMethod()
   {
      //Common task
      CallDelegate();
   }
}
```

The current solution is passing the object of parent class to all the 6 child class. Through which child classes access the common method.

I was wondering if there exist a better way to do the job.

For eg. making the commonMethod as static there for I don’t need to pass parent refrence to each child class. Also, I don’t want to make CommonMethod public.

Please suggest better approach or let me know if current implementation is good enough.

Comment: Do these child classes inherit from the parent?

Comment: No they don’t inherent from parent class. “Child” might be little confusing I guess.

Comment: Your Common method will always be public, else you will not be able to access it using object.

Comment: @Ashish That's not entirely correct. If the method is declared `internal` and child classes are declared inside the same assembly, they'll have access to the method.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the method as a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173172.aspx) to the child classes instead of the whole `ParentA` class. In this way, `Child` only needs to be given the method it wants to run, which is all it cares about.

```
public class ParentA
{
    Child B, C, D, E, F, G;

    public void Setup()
    {
        // pass CommonMethod or even just CallDelegate to the child classes
        B.SetParentMethod(this.CommonMethod);
        C.SetParentMethod(this.CommonMethod);
        D.SetParentMethod(this.CommonMethod);
        E.SetParentMethod(this.CommonMethod);
        F.SetParentMethod(this.CommonMethod);
        G.SetParentMethod(this.CommonMethod);
    }

    private void CommonMethod()
    {
        //Common task
        CallDelegate();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    private Action parentMethod;

    public void SetParentMethod(Action parentMethod)
    {
        this.parentMethod = parentMethod;
    }

    public void DoSomeAction()
    {
        // call the common task
        this.parentMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly equivalent to Rhumbori's solution, but using events. Either may be acceptable or preferrable to the other depending on your unstated requirements. Events impose some requirements on your method signatures and may not be appropriate.

```
class A {
    B x, y, z;

    void Init() {
        x.Something += Common;
        y.Something += Common;
        z.Something += Common;
    }

    void Common(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }
}

class B {
    public event EventHandler Something;

    public void OnSomething() {
        if (Something != null)
            Something(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```